# Is it mandatory to enable billing for HMS Core Site kit

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

When using the HMS core site kit, Is it mandatory to enable billing. What if it is not enabled?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Enterprise developer you have to subscribe to relevant pay-as-you-go plan to use paid APIs of Site kit, else you will face error 010027 as shown in the screenshot . This options is only for enterprise developers. This parameter is not required by individual developers.
[FAQ question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbN0o.png)
For more information about site kit pricing

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/about-charging-0000001052557393

For more information about general  pricing and quotas refer

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-service-billing